# dask-distributed: Improving speed on small dataframes

Tags: python, dask, dask-distributed

I am trying to use **dask** to offload work from a web-server to the workers for an interactive data analytics application. A simple `groupby()` and `mean()` is three times slower on `dask` compared to in-memory `pandas` computation, for the kind of data-frame size typical for my application. I understand this is not dask's objective. But, I find the dask distributed to be better fit to offload data in the interactive application (compared to Celery whose jobs can't be interactive).

Is there anything I can do to further improve the speed of computation apart from doing a persist. For example, Can I inform the system somehow that the dataframes are smaller so it is better to just get it executed on the node where the persisted data where the computation depends on lies?

```
csv = dd.read_csv(r'path-to-csv.csv')
df = csv.persist()

# Bringing to this machine
df2 = df.compute()

def f1():
    return df.groupby('Color').mean().compute()

def f2():
    return df2.groupby('Color').mean()

timeit.timeit('f1()', setup='from __main__ import f1', number=100)
timeit.timeit('f2()', setup='from __main__ import f2', number=100)
```

Answer (score 1):

[Modin](https://towardsdatascience.com/get-faster-pandas-with-modin-even-on-your-laptops-b527a2eeda74) might be the solution you are looking for.

You can find a comparison between Modin and Dask [here](https://github.com/modin-project/modin/issues/515).